# No puedo actualizar informacion BD desde c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Estoy realizando una busqueda y un update a la BD a traves de un SP, la busqueda si la hace y si me divuelve informacion el metodo, pero cuando hace un UPDATE no realiza la accion de actualizar, este es mi metodo

```
    public DataTable BuscaReactivaciones(string OperacionBD, string CadenaValores)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cadena))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "SP_BuscaReactivar";
                    if (OperacionBD=="Actualizar")
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cadena", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1, CadenaValores));
            
                    }                
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Opcion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OperacionBD;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    if (OperacionBD == "Buscar")
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    else if (OperacionBD == "Actualizar")
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }

                    if (Convert.ToString(command.Parameters["@Mensaje"].Value.ToString()) == "Exito")
                    {
                        EnviarCorreoCompleto("TEST CORREO");
                    }
                }


                return dt;
            }
```

el SP que uso es

```
    alter procedure SP_BuscaReactivar
     @Cadena nvarchar(max)=null,
     @Opcion varchar(100),
     @Mensaje varchar(250) OUTPUT

     as
     Begin
        IF @Opcion='Buscar'
        BEGIN
            select TOP 2 Consecutivo, Numero_de_contrato from CNR where clv_orden is not null 
            and resultado=2 
            and comando in('reactivar' , 'suspender', 'eliminar') 
            SET @Mensaje=''
        END
        ELSE IF @Opcion='Actualizar' 
        BEGIN

             UPDATE CNR SET mac_address='ABC'  WHERE CONSECUTIVO in (@Cadena)
            SET @Mensaje='Exito'
        END
     END
```

No se si sea por mi variable nvarchar(max) del SP que la estoy usando mal en C#

Comment: Intenta quitando el valor null en el parámetro del SP "@Cadena nvarchar(max)=null" . a simple vista supongo que en el where hay error ( WHERE CONSECUTIVO in (@Cadena)) por que la cadena es null. Trata de obtener los errores de SQL en C#

Comment: @ErickCastillo si le quito el null me genera una execpcion en adapter.fill(table) que dice El procedimiento o la función 'SP_BuscaReactivar' esperaba el parámetro '@Cadena', que no se ha especificado.'

Comment: según veo el SP necesitas ese dato en la opción actualizar. en ambos caso debes llenar los parámetros. desde c# pasarle el null

Comment: @ErickCastillo ya le pase el null desde c# pero cuando estoy en la Opcion Actualizar me genera un error en el ExecuteNonQuery(),  Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a bigint.

Comment: Para darte cuenta del error que se esta generando usa un [TRY...CATCH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

**Primera opción:**
Intenta agregando la palabra para ejecutar el procedimiento en la sección de CommandText:

```
command.CommandText = "EXEC SP_BuscaReactivar";
```

**Segunda opción:**
Intenta lo siguiente:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscaReactivar", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: me aparece una excepcion de esa forma:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'No se encontró el procedimiento almacenado 'EXEC SP_BuscaReactivar'.'

Comment: @Ivxn he agregado otra opción a la respuesta de como puedes mandar el nombre del procedimiento.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en la longitud de la cadena que le pasas como parámetro. Lo correcto es :

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cadena", SqlDbType.NVarChar, int.MaxValue, CadenaValores));
```

y en el procedimiento almacenado quitar el null en la variable cadena y dejarlo así:

```
 @Cadena nvarchar(max),
```