# Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a bigint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, .net

tengo un problema al hacer un update en BD SQL desde c# ya que desde mi aplicacion le envio los parametros requeridos a un SP y si llegan, pero no se por que al momento de hacer el update me genera una excepcion en c# que dice `Error al convertir el tipo de datos nvarchar a bigint.`

cabe destacar que dentro de la condicion para hacer el update coloco un campo que es de tipo bigint y yo le estoy enviando un nvarchar(ya que envio un tipo cadena con diversos valores numericos separados por coma) para enviar los valores de una sola vez y no uno por uno pero creo que necesito hacer una conversion o algo, si hago el update desde la BD y le coloco los valores igual separados por coma, si se ejecuta pero no se por que desde c# no se puede

De esta forma genero mi cadena de valores desde c#

```
                  foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        string valor = item["Consecutivo"].ToString();
                        var separador = ",";
                        
                        if (cadena=="")
                        {
                            //cadena +="'"+ valor+"'";
                            cadena += valor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //cadena += separador + "'"+valor+"'";
                            cadena += separador + valor;
                        }
                    }
```

asi envio mis parametros al SP

```
         public DataTable BuscaReactivaciones(string OperacionBD, string CadenaValores)
            {
      if (OperacionBD == "Actualizar")
                    {
                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadena);
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "SP_BuscaReactivar";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cadena", CadenaValores);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opcion", OperacionBD);

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mensaje", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Mensaje"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
           }
```

Mi SP  esta asi:

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BuscaReactivar]
     @Cadena nvarchar(max),
     @Opcion varchar(100),
     @Mensaje varchar(250) OUTPUT

     as
     Begin
        IF @Opcion='Buscar'
        BEGIN
            select TOP 2 Consecutivo, Numero_de_contrato from CNR where clv is not null 
            and resultado=2 
            and comando in('activar' , 'suspender') 
            SET @Mensaje=''
        END
        ELSE IF @Opcion='Actualizar' 
        BEGIN
             UPDATE CNR SET mac_address='ABC'  WHERE CONSECUTIVO in (@Cadena)
            SET @Mensaje='Exito'
        END
     END
```

El campo que es bigint es "Consecutivo"

Comment: aún no respondes la [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/515874/no-puedo-actualizar-informacion-bd-desde-c/516272#516272) tienes dos respuestas.  y es similar a esta pregunta

Comment: @ErickCastillo no he podido resolverla pero haciendo el analisis me di cuenta del campo que es bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta creando una variable varchar para generar una query para realizar el update. luego concatenas los valores , y lo ejecutas con execute. tu SP quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_BuscaReactivar]
     @Cadena nvarchar(max),
     @Opcion varchar(100),
     @Mensaje varchar(250) OUTPUT

     as
     Begin
        DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX);
        
        IF @Opcion='Buscar'
        BEGIN
            select TOP 2 Consecutivo, Numero_de_contrato from CNR where clv is not null 
            and resultado=2 
            and comando in('activar' , 'suspender') 
            SET @Mensaje=''
        END
        ELSE IF @Opcion='Actualizar' 
        BEGIN
            SET @Query = 'UPDATE CNR SET mac_address=' + CHAR(39) + 'ABC' + CHAR(39) + '  WHERE CONSECUTIVO in (' + @Cadena + ')'
            EXECUTE (@query)
            SET @Mensaje='Exito'
        END
     END
```

Comment: de esa forma si funciono, gracias!

Comment: he modificado mi respuesta. quité los char(39) del IN porque tu ya los estableces en la cadena en C#